# Why doesn't SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect work in AuthorizeAttribute.HandleUnauthorizedRequest override?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1

I've got an MVC 5.1 site with a controller with a single POST action. I have an Android app that I want to POST to it using basic authentication. I created a `BasicAuthorizeAttribute` class and applied it to my controller, and for testing purposes make it reject everything:

```
public class BasicAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I can step through my HandleUnauthorizedRequest in the debugger, but Fiddler shows the POST response is a 302 redirect to the login page. I thought `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` was supposed to prevent that. It's a problem because the Android app follows the redirect and gets 200 OK from the login request, so it appears the POST succeeded. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 200 OK status code is set upstream of the call to `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`. Explicitly clearing, setting and ending the response works. `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` doesn't appear to be necessary in this case.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been fighting this for a few hours. `.End()` does the trick. I thought this task was the very purpose of `.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`, so I really wonder where it _would_ work (anywhere?) and why it doesn't here.

Comment: This helped me solve a similar problem, but within Global.Application_Error() - Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `End()` did the trick for me also. Bottom line: Microsoft like in many cases engineered ASP.NET MVC. It's just way to complex, don't get me started on authentication. I don't know why they don't develop things simple? Instead of wondering ah this works, but I don't know why.

Like you mentioned `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect` where it would work?