# ASP.NET C# SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect not working for Ajax POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling an action within a controller decorated with a custom`[ApplicationAuthorize]` through an ajax POST and I want to be able to handle the case where a user is unauthenticated from the ajax response instead of having ASP.NET redirecting to the login page.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335849/why-doesnt-suppressformsauthenticationredirect-work-in-authorizeattribute-handl); won't work. I still get a 302. I also tried with the `SuppressFormsAuthentificationRedirect` attribute set to true in the override of the `HandleUnauthenticatedRequest` function of my custom authorize attribute, still won't work.

The custom authorize attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class,
                AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ApplicationAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var user = httpContext.User;

        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            else
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a working solution setup in Global.asax changing all responses with status 302 to 401 when Application_EndRequest occurs, but this is temporary and not the behavior I want as sometimes the redirection are legitimate.

This is what I'm having as response even with the custom authorize attribute described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335849/why-doesnt-suppressformsauthenticationredirect-work-in-authorizeattribute-handl).
`SaveAnswer` is the action in `SurveyController` called by the Ajax POST.
[image: Ajax POST Response]

For further understanding of the request/response pipeline of this problem see [this article.](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/suppressing-forms-authentcation-redirects/)

Any Ideas? I've been struggling with this problem for a few hours now...

Comment: Hey, If you have found any solution then please share

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order in which you call the base class. I bet that's what overwrites your response.

```
base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
// The rest of your code
```

Comment: Ok, it must be doing it inside the base method and hard-breaking the rest of the request pipeline. Not sure if there is a way to override the default behavior. You may just create your own and avoid the base class.

Comment: I tried to comment out the base class call, same result obtained. I believe the issue of the problem is later in the request pipeline as its modified by the FormsAuthentificationModule subscribed to the EndRequest event with the OnLeave event handler.  I added an article to the question for further understanding of the request/response pipeline.

Comment: This is not working buddy !! Have you ever checked it before posting?